# How to add custom text in the junit report for a cucumber-jvm run

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

We are using **bamboo** to pretty-print junit output for tests, and I would like to add some version information to the report.  Is there a way to do this?  I use following params:

```
--plugin junit:./output.xml --glue com.package.integrationtest
--plugin com.package.util.LogbackFormatter
```

I try to write the version in a step using the following:

```
stepdefs.scenario.write(String.format("version: %s",stepdefs.version);
```

This spits the string to the formatter (which redirects to logback) but it does not put the string in the junit formatter.  Is there a way to put the string in the junit output?

Comment: What version of cucumber jvm?

Comment: I'm using 1.2.2 right now.

Comment: Can you try 1.2.3? There have been a couple commits around formatting and reports, I don't think it resolves your issue, but it might. Also try: https://cucumber.io/support , that might work better than stackoverflow. Finally, an issue with a small reproduction repo on https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm if it's a legit bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use jUnit annotation method.

```
@After
public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    scenario.write("Text you want to write in junit report");
}
```